# C# & ASP.NET Core MVC Delete returns null from GetByIdAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When I click on the delete button in the web app, it returns this exception, so I guess `GetByIdAsync` returns null somehow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7TcD.png)

Here is the repository

```
public async Task<EducationalResource> GetByIdAsync(int id)
{
    return await _context.EducationalResources.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.resourceID == id);
}
```

Then here's the controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    var educationalresourceDetails = await _educationalresourceRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);

    if (educationalresourceDetails == null) 
        return View("Error");

    return View(educationalresourceDetails);
}

[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEducationalResource(int id)
{
    var educationalresourceDetails = await _educationalresourceRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);

    if (educationalresourceDetails == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    else
    {
        _educationalresourceRepository.Delete(educationalresourceDetails);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

And this is the `Delete` view:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Delete" >
    <input type="hidden" value="text" id="text" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="text">Title</label>
        <input asp-for="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text" readonly>
        <span asp-validation-for="text" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="link">Link</label>
        <input asp-for="link" class="form-control" placeholder="link" readonly>
        <span asp-validation-for="link" class="text-danger"></span>
</form> 
    
<div class="form-group">
    <form action="Delete" method="post">
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="resourceID" />
         <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-danger float-right mt-3" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I tried not making async and putting `?` in the int parameter but it does not work.

Comment: The screenshot shows that the *Model* in the view is null. This has nothing to do with EF Core, although the code doesn't really do what it claims. EF doesn't have nor need repositories, it *is* the repository. And `FirstOrDefaultAsync` doesn't return something by ID, that's what `FindAsync(id)` does. It searches for the first item that matches a condition and returns NULL if none is found

Comment: Should I change it to FindAsync?

Comment: What *do* you want to do is no match is found? Right now you're returning `return View("Error")`, which means the model *is* null. If this is expected, the view should be changed to check if the model is null or not

Comment: This is not a desired outcome, the Delete button always leads into the error

Comment: Hi Justin, could you kindly check the solution below and tell me if it works for you, thanks.

Comment: No, I don't want it to return an error, I can't get the Delete method to work

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your issue, here is my sample code.

```
@* Since there is ErrorViewModel in this page, we should pass new_error_model in `return View("Error",new_error_model);`  *@
@model ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>
```

And you can fix it like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    var educationalresourceDetails = await _educationalresourceRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);

    if (educationalresourceDetails == null) {
        ErrorViewModel m = new ErrorViewModel();
        m.RequestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return View("Error", m);
    }

    return View(educationalresourceDetails);
}
```